# Accessing your backend API without using CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, cors

I'm teaching myself web dev and am just getting into sending XMLHttpRequests from a client-facing page to an Express.js API backend.  In this particular case I'm using it to transmit form data and save it to a Mongo Database.

The specific issue I'm having is this:  I send it encoded as `application/json`, which throws me a cross-origin error because the Express.js API is running on `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.  I understand that requests to the same domain but a different port cause this error.

I've been able to get around it by doing `npm install cors` and then using `var cors = require('cors');` and `app.use(cors());` in my Express.js source, but as I understand it that will open the API up to requests from anywhere.  What if I really do just want it to only be accessible on my own domain?  I mean supposing it were a production site `mysite.com` and the form is at `mysite.com/form` and the backend is at `mysite.com:3000`.  I think I'm getting those example ideas right, but as I'm new to this I'm not sure.

How can I get them to be running on the same domain so as to not be doing a cross-origin request?  Is there a standard way to do this?  As of now I feel like to get the backend and the form running on the same port would require serving the form page from the Express.js backend itself, but what if I didn't want Express to be my server?  What if I wanted to serve pages some other way, from Apache or something, and just have this form on there that sends its data off to Express for processing?  Or if I wanted to have an Angular app running that POSTs data to the Express backend, again for processing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with CORS, you can configure it to stick to a certain origin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors
But keep in mind that this doesn't prevent from someone else accessing your API via a simple `curl` command. CORS is there to guard the browser, not the API.

A better approach (that you mentioned yourself) would be to have both parts running at the same domain and port. This can be achieved by proxying the requests. In Express you could simply deliver your frontend code as static assets with [express.static()](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in). In Apache you could also add some proxying, though I cannot help you there, as I'm not that familiar with Apache modules and setups.

Securing your API from third-party access is another topic. You'll need some form of authentication and authorization. Doing that right can be hard. Perhaps you should have a look at [Oauth 2](https://oauth.net/2/) for a proven standard.

Comment: This: A better approach (that you mentioned yourself) would be to have both parts running at the same domain and port.

Comment: "CORS is there to guard the browser, not the API" - if this is so, then how come enabling CORS on the Express side of things allows the POST request to work?  It seems like the Express API is refusing the connection rather than the browser.

Comment: Normaly a browser is adhering the same origin policy. Here you can read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy By using CORS this policy is disabled for certain domains, permitting cross origin access. It's still the browsers decision, if it really executes the request or not. The server just tells it whether it "should fulfill the request" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) So your browser asks "is my domain save for access", and if so, it interprets the result. Otherwise it stops by throwing an exception. Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: +1 I was all set to answer, but it appears that all points have already been well covered. I would like to emphasize the need for an authentication/authorization implementation for the API. It does not matter if your API is on the same domain as the client, or on a different domain; HTTP requests can be made against your API from anywhere, if the API is external facing. As mentioned, browsers are simply written to obey the same origin policy, which is why they can only access your API if certain conditions are met.